# Syntax Error: Lateral Join with Delete (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, lateral

PostgreSQL 11.1

AFAIK, this is correct and should run. It Fails with syntax error on Delete.  What am I missing?

Thanks for any help.

*ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DELETE"
LINE 41:        DELETE FROM d*

```
WITH _in (tservice, patient_recid, disease_recid, new_disease_recid) AS (
        VALUES ('2021-04-21'::timestamp, '23262'::integer, '34978'::integer, '33364'::integer)    
)
UPDATE dx d
SET disease_recid = n.new_disease_recid
FROM _in n,
    LATERAL ( WITH RECURSIVE readtoend AS(
                SELECT recid, newrecid
                    FROM patients p1
                    JOIN _in n ON p1.recid = n.patient_recid
                UNION
                SELECT  c.recid, c.newrecid
                    FROM patients c
                    INNER JOIN readtoend s ON s.newrecid = c.recid
            ),
            readtostart AS(
                SELECT recid, newrecid
                        FROM patients p1
                        JOIN _in n ON p1.recid = n.patient_recid
                    UNION
                    SELECT c.recid, c.newrecid
                        FROM patients c
                        INNER JOIN readtostart s ON s.recid = c.newrecid
            )
                SELECT recid FROM readtoend
                UNION
                SELECT recid FROM readtostart            
            ) j,
    LATERAL ( WITH _get_existing_target AS(                               
                    SELECT d.*
                    FROM d
                    WHERE (d.patient_recid, d.disease_recid) = (j.recid, n.new_disease_recid) AND d.tservice <= n.tservice
                ),
                 _get_conflicts AS(                                    
                    SELECT d.*
                    FROM d  
                    WHERE (d.patient_recid, d.disease_recid) = (j.recid, n.disease_recid) AND EXISTS (  SELECT 1
                                    FROM _get_existing_target x
                                    WHERE d.patient_recid = x.patient_recid AND d.tservice::date = x.tservice::date)
                )
                DELETE FROM d
                USING _get_conflicts f
                WHERE d.recid = f.recid
                RETURNING d.*
                ) del
WHERE (d.patient_recid, d.disease_recid)  = (j.recid, n.disease_recid) AND d.tservice::date <= n.tservice::date
       AND  d.recid NOT IN ( SELECT recid FROM del);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `DELETE ... RETURNING` in the `FROM` list of a query.

Comment: Even removing it still causes the same syntax error. :(  ???

Comment: Removing delete will surely **not** cause the a syntax error about `DELETE`.

Comment: I think I missed your point :( . I still have a syntax error without "returning". Suggestions??

Comment: No, because your query is too convoluted to penetrate. But surely you can rewrite it so that there is no `DELETE` in a correlated subquery.

Comment: It can be easily rewritten by putting al the CTE's together and not using LATERAL at all. So doing, does require the RETURNING syntax, but does run and compile smoothly.  LATERAL poses the problem :(

Comment: Yes, exactly. `LATERAL` makes the task non-trivial.